# Which version of Java is supported by Eclipse Helios?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, selenium-webdriver, helios

I'm new to Eclipse and Java. Whenever I run the Java program in Eclipse there is a major.minor 52 exception. I want to know which version of Java is supported by Eclipse Helios. My computer is Windows 7 32-bit OS. So I can't download any other version of Eclipse. Please help me with a favorable answer.

Comment: Get Java 8 or newer

Comment: Downvoted because no research. This is answered by just going to Wikipedia, Eclipse. Which lists all versions and their supported Java. This is also answered by just googling this particular error message. Please read [ask], thanks. Apart from that, the question lacks any details about the error message. It should have the full error message included and a more detailed description of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The class file major.minor version 52 error means that Java 8 or newer is required.

Eclipse Helios (3.6) is very old (10 years and 14 releases old). It probably doesn't understand anything above Java 6.

There are 32 bit version of Eclipse newer than this.
Eclipse 4.9 (2018-09) was the last 32 bit Eclipse - that supports Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Lets start with some [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases).

Eclipse Helios (3.6) was released in 2010.  It supported the latest version of Java that was available at the time; i.e. Java 7.

Eclipse Juna (4.4) was the first release of Eclipse to support Java 8 language features.

Java 7 has been end-of-life for a few years now.

Java 8 (the oldest available version of Java with free support) was released in 2014.  This corresponds to the classfile version number (52) of the application that you are trying to run.

Java 8 is also that last version of Java for which you can get a Windows 32 bit version from Oracle.

---

So what can you do?

If you want to run a pre-built Java application which has classfile version 52, you will have to download and install Java 8.

If you are prepared to rebuild the application, then depending on the application you will probably still need to upgrade to Java 8 to do that.  (It depends on whether the application uses Java 8 language constructs or library classes and methods that were introduced in Java 8.  It is likely that one or both of those is true.)

If you are going to upgrade to Java 8, it would be advisable to Eclipse to (at least) Luna, but you could go all the way to the 2018-03 release ... which is the last version that supported 32bit Windows.

You could probably also run the application from the command line; i.e. without using any IDE at all.  But that would apply to a tool that was designed to run as an Eclipse plugin, etc.

But my strongest advice is to get a machine that can run a 64 bit OS.  You can probably get one for USD $300 or less.  If your current hardware cannot run a 64bit OS, it must be pretty old, and I am surprised that it still  works reliably.

---

> Which version of Java is supported by Eclipse Helios?

Java 7 and earlier versions.

> So I can't download any other version of Eclipse.

That is not true.  But simply upgrading Eclipse won't solve the problem.  You need to upgrade Java as well if you want to run that application.